# About fork() while building a shell

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell

here is my code.

```
pid_t fpid=fork();
if(fpid > 0){
    wait(&fpid);
}
else{
    do_command();
}
```

The thing is, the function do_command() only execute one line, so I change  the do_command() for this:

```
else{
    execlp("/bin/ls","ls","-al",NULL);
    cout<<"\ntest<<endl;
}
```

Also, the ls command was executed but cout command was missing..

What's wrong with my code?

Please excuse my poor English and help me.

Here is my do_command() function declaration:

```
void do_command(const char *command) {

    //all commands with arguments


    const char *kernel_address = "/bin/";
    char *kernel_command;
    strcpy(kernel_command, kernel_address);
    strcat(kernel_command, command);

    cout << "\nCommand is:" << kernel_command << "\n" << endl;

    execlp(kernel_command, command, NULL);


}
```

Also, there is no any output while function was called in child process

Comment: Have you studied some [documentation of `execlp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp)? Notice especially the "Return value" section.

Comment: you char *kernel_command does not have memory allocated? Have you allocated memory for *kernel_command using malloc()?

Comment: This `wait(&fpid);` is not nice. `wait()` expects an `int *`.

Answer (score 0):

The next line is not printing because the exec family commands only returns on error. If there is no error, it will replace you program and whatever command intended to be executed in exec, is executed. Therefore cout is not working

Comment: @HoweChen It's not your code that needs fixing, it's your assumptions about how certain library calls work that needs to be adjusted, as several comments and answers have pointed out...

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual of execlp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) :

> The exec() family of functions *replaces* the current process image with a new process image.

Once your `execlp` is called, your program is not running anymore. It has been replaced by `ls`. Thus, it will never reach the `cout`